# Clopen set $S=\{x \in \mathbb{Q}: -\pi<x<\pi\}$ on $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: real-analysis

I was reading through Pugh's Real Mathematical Analysis when I came across the example of $S=\{x \in \mathbb{Q}: -\pi<x<\pi\}$ on $\mathbb{Q}$ as a clopen set. I can see pretty clearly why $S$ is open, but I cannot see why it is closed.

Comment: What's the definition of closed that you're working with? $S$ contains all its limit points. The set $\mathbb{Q}-S$ is also open in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: A set $S$ is closed if for every sequence in $S$ where the limit exists, the limit is also in $S$ - is the definition I'm working with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It equals $[-\pi,\pi]\cap\Bbb Q$. In $\Bbb R$, the set $[-\pi,\pi]$ is closed, and
$A\cap \Bbb Q$ is closed in $\Bbb Q$ whenever $A$ is closed in $\Bbb R$.
($\Bbb Q$ has the subspace topology induced from $\Bbb R$).

Comment: I'm wondering about the sequence $\{3,3.1,3.14,3.141,...\}$. If we were in $\mathbb{R}$, the limit is $\pi$ but given that we are working in $\mathbb{Q}$, how do we know that the limit is in $S$?

Comment: The limit isn't in $S$. Being closed requires that if a limit exist then it is contained in the set. That sequence doesn't even have a limit when we are working in $\mathbb{Q}$.